# Are there any Eclipse plugins to display a visual object graph in debug mode?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

Is there any such tool for Eclipse to draw a visual graph for a given object as the root in debug mode? Something like [Stan4J](http://stan4j.com/dependencies/dependency-analysis.html) but more focused on objects and fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is [DoodleDebug](http://scg.unibe.ch/wiki/projects/DoodleDebug). It's not a debugger extension, but a tool with similar usage as `System.out.prinln()`. You can install it as an Eclipse plugin and it comes with a short tutorial. The default representation of non-standard Java objects is printing their class name and included fields.

Comment: Thanks @Cedric, this looks exactly like what I was looking for.  [link to screenshot](https://wiki.eclipse.org/sites/default/files/styles/ds_solution_screenshot/public/output_maps-lists_1.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [java spider](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaspider/). Not very user friendly, but you can get kind of an object graph. (btw. this is a plugin from Kent Beck and Erich Gamma...)